# Google Sheets - Formula to reference next cell in same row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have two columns where I cam looking up a value in another sheet for date and value. The values are in rows and I want to display the results in columns.

[How the source data looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NHtG.png)

[How I'm pulling it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdRwc.png)

I can't figure how to make the formula drag down where Column value changes, but the Row value stays the same. Meaning, AA1 would drag down to AB1, AC1, etc.

```
105 Weds Feb 1 at 9:00 AM
101 Weds Feb 1 at 12:00 PM
115 Weds Feb 1 at 4:05 PM
111 Weds Feb 1 at 9:40 PM
116 Thurs Feb 2 at 12:05 AM
97  Thurs Feb 2 at 1:20 PM
```

```
='Data'!B1   ='Data'!B3
='Data'!C1   ='Data'!C3
='Data'!D1   ='Data'!D3
```

I've tried using an array and it works for the displaying the next value in the Column, but not the next value in the Row like I want.

I've also tried some scripts I was able to lookup but wasn't successful.

Comment: Have you tried the [TRANSPOSE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) ?!

Comment: Ugh, I'm dumb. he original data was being Transposed from another source, so just redoing worked perfectly. Thank you